# How to draw a complex line bundle?

Tags: differential-topology, visualization, vector-bundles

The most basic example of a topologically non-trivial real line bundle is the well-known *Möbius strip*. Everyone who learns about vector bundles will be confronted by it, if only because it has the distinguished advantage that we can draw a picture of it.

[image]

I would like to *draw pictures* of other line bundles, too. In particular, I have a complex line bundle which I would like to visualize somehow. How do I do that?

To be more specific:

- The base manifold is the torus $M = S^1\times S^1$. It should be fine to visualize it as a rectangle, though.
- The complex line bundle has structure group $U(1)$.
- It is given as a direct summand of the trivial bundle $M \times L^2(\mathbb R^3)$. In other words, it is embedded in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space bundle. In particular, there is an induced connection coming from the hermitian form (scalar product).
- (The bundle arises from an analysis of the Quantum Hall Effect.)

My questions:

> 1) Are there any example drawings of complex line bundles?

I imagine that one attaches a plane to every point of the base manifold, but it is not clear how to me how to arrange them such that one obtains a qualitative picture of the fact that they represent complex numbers.

> 2) Is there a minimal dimension $N$ such that every complex line bundle can be embedded into $\mathbb R^N$ in a suitable fashion?

It is probably the case that $N \geq 4$, so this won't be of much use, but it might still shed some insight on the problem, in particular because we are also given a connection.

> 3a) Any ideas of how one might go about drawing a complex line bundle?
>
> 3b) Any ideas on how to best visualize the connection coming from a hermitian form?

Comment: I have no idea of what «a qualitative picture of the fact that they represent complex numbers» is!

Comment: As far as I know, the standard way of visualizing this sort of thing is via sparse pointwise illustrations of the structure - for instance, the Wikipedia picture of surface normals ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Surface_normal.png ) shows the simplest example of this sort of visualization.

Comment: @Steven: How does that apply to non-trivial vector bundles? I mean, the normal bundle of a sphere is trivial, hence easy to draw. In contrast, trying to draw a Moebius strip on a 2D piece of paper via sparse pointwise illustration seems like a hopeless task?

Comment: @Greg: The version of the Moebius strip I've seen basically draws a local bundle (in the Mobius case, a line) and then parallel transports it around the strip to show the non-trivial nature.  Of course, this mostly works because there's an almost-trivial holonomy involved; you can show the global nature at one point.  In your case, if the connection isn't essentially flat that could be a severe complication... :/

Comment: @Steven: Yeah, in my case the connection is not flat, it has curvature at every point of the torus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, Mario Serna has produced pictures of $U(1)$-bundles on his [webpage](http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/MarioSerna/GaugeGeometryResearch/) and in his paper ["Riemannian Gauge Theory and Charge Quantization"](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0205250). Here an example

[image]

The image represents a trivial $\mathbb R^3$ over some rectangular base manifold. The $U(1)$ bundle which we want to visualize is shown as an $\mathbb R^2$-sub-bundle: the disks indicate the 2-dimensional fibers at each point, to be understood as subspaces of small 3-dimensional boxes at each point (not shown).

It seems that the disks are also meant to give an impression of the connection, but I don't fully understand how parallel transport is supposed to work here.

He cites a result by Narasimhan and Ramanan which says that every $U(1)$ bundle can be embedded into a trivial $(2d+1)$-dimensional complex vector bundle where $d = \text{dim} M$ is the dimension of the base manifold. Fortunately, the dimension is lower in the cases drawn.

Answer (score 3):

In any case... try making pictures of the bundle of unit circles associated to your complex line bundle, which has one dimension less. If the base space is the torus $S^1\times S^1$, then the total space of the circle bundle can be constructed by identifying faces of a cube, and *that* is something one can make pictures of.

If you described the actual bundle of which you want a picture, then someone could come up with something sensible. The general problem of «drawing complex line bundles» is pretty hopeless.

Comment: The line bundle arises as a collection of 1D eigenspaces $X_k$ of the Hamilton operator $H(k) = \frac1{2m}(-i\hbar\partial_x+\hbar k_x+By)^2 + (-i\hbar\partial_y+\hbar k_y)^2$ in case that helps. :-P I'm happy to do the calculations myself, it's just that seeing some (literal) prior art would greatly simplify the task of figuring out what to draw. The thing is that I want to somehow "draw" the connection, too, but I'm not even sure that I can choose a global gauge (first Chern number is non-zero). What does a bundle of circles look like that doesn't have any globally non-zero sections??

Comment: @Greg: that does not tell me anything. Unless you can provide some concrete imnformation about how the bundle is put together, you are *not* going to be able to make any picture at all...

Comment: You mean a system of local trivializations with corresponding transition functions? I haven't made the effort of calculating one yet. (Which could be a good idea, thanks.) A priori, my line bundle is given by a family of projections, very much like the tangent bundle to the sphere $TS^2 \subseteq S^2\times\mathbb R^3$ is given by the family of projections $P_x v = v - \langle x,v\rangle x$ where $x \in S^2, v \in \mathbb{R}^3$.